# Integrate bootstrap in grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm new in grails and I'm trying to integrate bootstrap, but I have and error in the label r: I'm trying to find some good tutorial to integrate bootstrap in grails but I can't find anything, and anything good solution.

I add in BuildConfig ( I can see that bootstrap is installed in my link_to_grails_plugins)

```
compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4"
```

I did, this too:

"To include your bootstrap resources add the following to your application's css or js file."

```
Javascript grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

//= require bootstrap

console.log("My javascript goes here");
Stylesheet grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.css:

/*
*= require bootstrap
*/
```

And this....
    Layout

Your grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I put in my view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello World </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<r:require modules="bootstrap"/>` is mark in yellow and i can read Unknown tag (r:require).

Comment: `<r:require />` comes from the resource plugin. WIth current versions of grails, `asset-pipeline` is the default plugin to serve assets. That's why your IDE does not know about this tag. When using asset-pipeline, you can remove it, because `<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>` already does the trick. In your own answer, you declare bootstrap twice - i don't think this is a good idea. You have to decide about the dependency scope - `compile` or `runtime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution. You have to add in your BuildConfig.groovy this:

runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4'

I show all the code that you have to have in plugins:

```
plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4'

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
```